# Getting a segmentation fault in the below C code?

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

Why I am getting a segmentation fault in the code given below?

```
char getstr()
{
  static char s[]="Hiii2015";
  return s;
}

int main()
{
  printf("%s",getstr());
  return 0;
}
```

Although I know I am returning an address using a `char` return type , and the return type must be `char*` but still if I do like this only then I am getting null on gcc compiler and segmentation fault on another compiler so what is the reason for this

Answer (score 5):

Your return type for `getstr()` is wrong.

It's just `char`,  should be `const char *` or `char *`, i.e. a pointer.

As is, you're squishing the returned pointer down to `char` (probably just 8 bits) and then trying to access that very low address from `printf()` gives you undefined behavior.

You should have been getting a compiler warning for this.

Answer (score 3):

> *I am getting null on gcc compiler and segmentation fault on another compiler*

Very profound sign of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). In your code,

```
printf("%s",getstr());
```

actually invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as the supplied argument is not the proper type as expected by the supplied format specifier.

To elaborate a bit on this, quoting `C11` standard, chapter §6.8.6.4, `return` statement,

> If a `return` statement with an expression is executed, the value of the expression is
>   returned to the caller as the value of the function call expression. If the expression has a
>   type different from the return type of the function in which it appears, the value is
>   converted as if by assignment to an object having the return type of the function.

So, `s` is returned as if converted to a `char`, representing a wrong value. That value, when being supplied as the argument to `%s`, creates all the issues via UB.

Upon encountering UB, the behavior is neither guaranteed nor be predicted.